# Tracking User Ids on Google Analytics

Tags: asp.net, google-analytics

I would like to track user ids of the logged in users on google analytics. The system I am talking about is an ASP.Net Webforms application, when user logins to the system the user id of the authenticated user is stored in a session variable i.e. Session["UserId"] and used everywhere in the system just to check whether user is an authentic user or not. My question is how can I let GA know about that Session variable so that GA tracks every user id and provide results of the activities user performed on the website.

Tracking is already being done for page views and it is working fine.

If required I can provide more details about the problem.

Thanks.

Comment: Hi! Welcome to SO. You'll get a much better and efficient help from the community if you add code and describe your attempt along with your problems. At least the skeleton of what you have so we can help you include the missing parts

Answer (score 0):

This guide explains exactly how to do it:
https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/analyticsjs/cookies-user-id

Here's the gist:

```
ga('create', 'UA-XXXXX-Y', 'auto');

// Make sure USER_ID is unique and doesn't contain any
// personally identifiable information.
ga('set', 'userId', USER_ID);
ga('send', 'pageview');
```